# Converting list into field with PyQGIS

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-3, fields-attributes, list

I am trying to convert a few lists into fields.
I have no problem creating the fields. I just don't have any idea on how to fill them.

```py
if result:
    layer = self.dlg.comboLayerLine.currentData()
    features = layer.getFeatures()
    ID = []
    X = []
    Y = []
    for feature in features:
        geom = feature.geometry()
            
        if geom.type() == QgsWkbTypes.PointGeometry:
            co = geom.asPoint()

            ID.append(feature.id())
            X.append(co[0]
            Y.append(co[1])

        elif geom.type() == QgsWkbTypes.LineGeometry:
            #Do the same with Line geometry

        elif geom.type() == QgsWkbTypes.PolygonGeometry:
            #Do the same with PolyLine geometry
           
        elif geom.type() == QgsWkbTypes.UnknownGeometry:
            #Prompt error box for unknown geometry

        #Add fields here
```

Here I make 3 differents lists. I want to convert each of them into 3 differents fields.

Edit: I was about to add a sample of the lists I get but I realized they don't even appear anymore! Here is the rest of my code.

```py
new_layer = QgsVectorLayer(r'D:\Users\user\Desktop\trash temp', "essai.shp", "ogr") 
new_layer.startEditing() 
id_field = QgsField('ID', QVariant.String)
x_field = QgsField('X', QVariant.String)
y_field = QgsField('Y', QVariant.String)
new_layer.addAttribute(id_field)
new_layer.addAttribute(x_field)
new_layer.addAttribute(y_field)
print("Ok pressed")
```

Edit 2: I managed to fix the lists so here is the output of the list "y":

```
[6414701.507300033, 6416326.521299997, 6414870.419924344, 6414629.207300014, 6414839.753699968, 6414545.455399935, 6414596.490248112, 6414756.708799932, 6414599.551207293, 6414792.136099978, 6414952.573700016, 6414714.024700028, 6414630.641128357, 6414606.850143043, 6414661.849399988, 6414634.387000008, 6414601.288791229, 6414930.830580306, 6414609.777690075]
```

Edit 3: I tried something which didn't work. here it is:

```
#Add fields here 
layerFields = QgsFields()
layerFields.append(QgsField('ID', QVariant.Int))
layerFields.append(QgsField('x', QVariant.Double))
layerFields.append(QgsField('y', QVariant.Double))
path = r'D:\Users\me\Desktop\trash temp'
writer = QgsVectorFileWriter(path, 'UTF-8', layerFields, QgsWkbTypes.Point)
feat = QgsFeature(layerFields)
feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(attrs[1], attrs[2])))
for i in range(2, len(attrs), 3):
   print(attrs)
   feat.setAttributes(attrs[i-2], attrs[i-1], attrs[i])
   writer.addFeature(feat)

#Finish

layer = iface.addVectorLayer(fn, '','ogr')
del(writer)
```

It returns me the following error:

> feat.setAttributes(attrs[i-2], attrs[i-1], attrs[i])   TypeError:
> QgsFeature.setAttributes(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'

Edit 4: After receiving a few advices, I decided to make a list of lists. So my new output is:

```
[[0, 506099.200000004, 6414701.507300033], [1, 505724.36900000286, 6416326.521299997], [2, 506076.8426659516, 6414870.419924344], [3, 506265.86200000404, 6414629.207300014], [4, 506945.2999999959, 6414839.753699968], [5, 506180.2869999982, 6414545.455399935], [6, 506047.2159920711, 6414596.490248112], [7, 506081.38259999966, 6414756.708799932], [8, 506045.6930898201, 6414599.551207293], [9, 506816.1533999958, 6414792.136099978], [10, 506090.7625000037, 6414952.573700016], [11, 506660.63870000176, 6414714.024700028], [12, 506112.8389316339, 6414630.641128357], [13, 506134.08904640994, 6414606.850143043], [14, 506548.10649999965, 6414661.849399988], [15, 506436.27269999706, 6414634.387000008], [16, 506303.8354239211, 6414601.288791229], [17, 506062.6988654828, 6414930.830580306], [18, 506047.52282746276, 6414609.777690075]]
```

Each list represents a future feature with its ID, X and Y coordinate

Comment: I did add the field ! The fact is that I absolutely don't know how to put those lists in the fields ! I actually looked for it but couldn't find much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try the following code:

```py
layer = QgsVectorLayer("Point", "Test", "memory")
crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem("EPSG:26912")
layer.setCrs(crs)

provider = layer.dataProvider()
provider.addAttributes([QgsField('ID', QVariant.Int),
                        QgsField('X', QVariant.Double),
                        QgsField('Y', QVariant.Double)])
layer.updateFields()

attributes = [[0, 506099.200000004, 6414701.507300033], [1, 505724.36900000286, 6416326.521299997], [2, 506076.8426659516, 6414870.419924344], [3, 506265.86200000404, 6414629.207300014], [4, 506945.2999999959, 6414839.753699968], [5, 506180.2869999982, 6414545.455399935], [6, 506047.2159920711, 6414596.490248112], [7, 506081.38259999966, 6414756.708799932], [8, 506045.6930898201, 6414599.551207293], [9, 506816.1533999958, 6414792.136099978], [10, 506090.7625000037, 6414952.573700016], [11, 506660.63870000176, 6414714.024700028], [12, 506112.8389316339, 6414630.641128357], [13, 506134.08904640994, 6414606.850143043], [14, 506548.10649999965, 6414661.849399988], [15, 506436.27269999706, 6414634.387000008], [16, 506303.8354239211, 6414601.288791229], [17, 506062.6988654828, 6414930.830580306], [18, 506047.52282746276, 6414609.777690075]]

for attr in attributes:
    f = QgsFeature()
    f.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(attr[1], attr[2])))
    f.setAttributes(attr)
    provider.addFeature(f)

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

The output will look like:

[image: result]

---

**References:**

- [PyQGIS 101: Creating & editing a new vector layer](https://anitagraser.com/pyqgis-101-introduction-to-qgis-python-programming-for-non-programmers/pyqgis101-creating-editing-a-new-vector-layer/)
- [OpenSourceOptions | PyQGIS: Create a Point Feature](https://opensourceoptions.com/blog/pyqgis-create-a-point-feature/)

Comment: Your code worked perfectly ! Thank you very much for your help.
By the way, I'm working with espg:26912.